# css selectors, IE and html doctypes

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-selectors, doctype

Im writing html and css in an old web application that is using the following doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
```

If i change it to html5 doctype, the menu wont work. My problem is that i cant use some css selectors, like

```
input[type="radio"]
```

for instance. But this obviously works with the html5 doctype. Any possible solutions for this? Thanks!

Comment: There's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801470/ie-support-for-attribute-selectors-with-html5-doctype What versions of IE are you testing in? 7, 8, 9? They're all supposed to recognize attribute selectors with a doctype.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, forgot to mention that im testing in ie7 & 8

Comment: I think the problem in this case is that the page runs in quirks mode as default for some reason

Comment: OK, now I'm confused. Are you already using such selectors in your CSS? Do they work now or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doctype you mentioned (HTML 4.0 Transitional without URL) triggers quirks mode. This causes that Internet Explorer's rendering is similar to IE5. Your website works fine in quirks mode probably because it's optimized for such old versions of IE: for example, it may assume the border-box box model. Naturally, you cannot use more complicated CSS selectors because IE5 didn't support them. The solution is to rewrite the code for standards mode rendering. The usual approach is to develop the application with HTML5 doctype in standards-compliant browsers like Firefox, Chrome or IE9 and then try to fix bugs that can appear in older versions of Internet Explorer.

Comment: The OP is saying it was originally rendering in almost standards mode, with advanced selectors being supported, but no longer with the HTML5 doctype. Except, the HTML5 doctype was created **so that** IE would **not** render in quirks mode.

Comment: @BoltClock I don't see your point. If application works with HTML 4.0 Transitional doctype without URL, it's definitely optimized for quirks mode and this has to be changed. I can't see where OP said that "it was originally rendering in standards mode".

Comment: Oh I get it now, I completely missed that it wasn't pointing to a URL.

Comment: @BoltClock - For future reference - `-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN` always causes quirks mode, with or without a URL. `-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN` causes quirks mode only if the URL is missing. - see: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#the-initial-insertion-mode

Answer (score 0):

I've solved many of my problems with selectors and previous IE version by just including this javascript library (it needs jQuery or some other library to work):

http://selectivizr.com

It worths a shot.

> selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes
>   and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8.

Comment: It doesn't appear to emulate CSS2 attribute selectors.